# In the Spring boot, when I fetch data from DB, error popping List is null, but data available in db table

Tags: spring-boot

data not fetching, error thrown list is empty but data available in DB

service class code,

[Service class code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJfT6.png)

Controller class
[Controller code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWijH.png)

error msg
[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXMyY.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text not in images

Answer (score 0):

You must add @Autowired to have a dependency injected:

```
@Autowired
private country gocount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bean wiring is missing here hence null pointer exception is being thrown.

You need to do one of the following.

1. Autowire the dependency

@Autowired
private Country repocount;

2. Make a constructor and set this dependency.
3. Using a Lombok annotation may also help.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the error it is cleared that You haven't Autowired the Bean In controller this will surely solve the problem